# Find the distance in a path between each node and the last node of the path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am very new to Cypher and I need help to solve a problem I am facing..
In my graph I have a path represeting a data stream and I need to know, for each node in the path, the distance from the last node of the path.
For example if i have the following path:

(a)->(b)->(c)->(d)

the distance must be 3 for a, 2 for b, 1 for c and 0 for d.
Is there an efficient way to obtain this result in Cypher?
Thanks a lot!

Mauro

Comment: when you say "distance" do you mean number of hops? Or are you refering to a property you manintain on the relationships between the nodes?

Answer (score 2):

If it is just hops between nodes then i think this will fit the bill.

```
match p=(a:Test {name: 'A'})-[r*3]->(d:Test {name: 'D'}) 
with p, range(length(p),0,-1) as idx
unwind idx as elem
return (nodes(p)[elem]).name as Node
, length(p) - elem as Distance
order by Node
```

Comment: Hi Dave, your query fits the bill, but I found a couple of problems: some performance issues (the graph is quite complex and the machines have slow performances) and the presence of cycles in the graph. So I think that I must find a different approach to the task... Thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I define a path to be "complete" if its start node has no incoming relationship and its end node has no outgoing relationship.

This query returns, for each "complete" path, a collection of objects containing each node's neo4j-generated ID and the number of hops to the end of that path:

```
MATCH p=(x)-[*]->(y)
WHERE (NOT ()-->(x)) AND (NOT (y)-->())
WITH NODES(p) AS np, LENGTH(p) AS lp
RETURN EXTRACT(i IN RANGE(0, lp, 1) | {id: ID(np[i]), hops: lp - i})
```

NOTE: Matching with `[*]` will be costly with large graphs, so you may need to limit the maximum hop value. For example, use `[*..4]` instead to limit the max hop value to 4.

Also, qualifying the query with appropriate node labels and relationship types may speed it up.

Comment: Hi Sam, your query works great but, like I told to Dave before, I found a couple of problems: some performance issues (the graph is quite complex and the machines have slow performances - you warned about that) and the presence of cycles in the graph. I think I must find a different approach to the task... Thanks a lot for the help!!